# PHP, Submit form on load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to submit a form immediately when a PHP file is visited in the browser.  How can I do this: Preferably in jQuery.

Details:

I have a form that once submitted inserts some data into a database and sends the user to a separate page.  On the separate page, I have code for another form that then directs users to pay for whatever they have selected.

I don't want the user to have to click submit on the second form in order for them to pay. So is there a way to make that form submit automatically and thus direct the user to the payment stage?

Comment: So why don't you redirect the user to the payment stage in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke the `submit` method:

```
$("#formID").submit();
```

So, at your second page:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#your-formID").submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: This does answer the question literally, but it's really bad advice.

Comment: @Jon I answered the question. The OP didn't ask for the best method to go from page 1 to 3, but from 1 to 2 to 3. Did you downvote my answer for answering that question?

Comment: Here, have an upvote. My upvote shall compensate his downvote.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing the best method then?

Comment: @AlexYoucefSaidani If you have access to the PHP code which processes both forms, concatenate them (*not* by copy-pasting the second file's contents at the first one!). Otherwise, use the code as provided at the answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this

```
<body onload="submitForm()" ></body>


<script>
function submitForm()
{
 document.frm.submit();
}
</script>
```

frm is name of form

Answer (score 0):

Why does that form exist if it is submitted automatically? Make the first form redirect directly to the third page and handle the rest on the server. No need to send the data to the client if it is not used there. And automatically posting using Javascript may not work on each client. Eliminate the risk by doing it server side.

Comment: I don't actually have access to the code in the second script so I have to submit to that form in order for the script to run.

Comment: Alright. Would have been a good idea to mention that. :) But if you don't have access to the code, how do you have access to the html/javascript it outputs?